# How to create parent and two child tables mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a parent table named grade:

```
classid classname 
   1     classone
   2     classtwo
```

Two child tables named classone and classtwo.

classone table:

```
studentid  studentname
   1        john
   2        snow
```

classtwo table:

```
studentid studentname
   1         Tyrion
   2         Lannister
```

How to create these tables with primary key and foreign key?

I am newer in mysql database, Who can help me ?

Comment: format and typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **FOREIGN KEY (classId) REFERENCES Grade(classId)** to each foreign table:

```
CREATE TABLE Grade(
    classId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(classId),
    className VARCHAR(255),
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE Classone(
    studentId  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(studentId),
    studentName VARCHAR(255),
    classId CHAR(40),
    FOREIGN KEY (classId) REFERENCES Grade(classId)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE Classtwo(
   studentId  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(studentId),
    studentName VARCHAR(255),
    classId CHAR(40),
    FOREIGN KEY (classId) REFERENCES Grade(classId)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Remember, you also need to add classId in each foreing table to match them. So i also added two colums for these class tables.

Comment: ,Thankyou, it works fine.I suppose you are a DB export. I have another question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580234/how-to-insert-many-datas-of-value-in-while-loop-sentence-mysql-php

Comment: @stack i'm at work today but i will give it a look as soon as i can.