# How to insert many datas of value in while loop sentence. mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Transaction is used in my PHP page.Because hpcid is the foreign key of IDC table.

I have one hundred rows of people information (name,id,phone) would be inserted into IDC table, so i want to use while loop.

Without while loop, I tested three row data of people info,it works fine.But when while loop is added, it works failed.

Here, the code works OK:

```
$query="begin ;
    insert into HPC (name, begindata, enddate) VALUES('".$_POST['customerName']."','".$_POST['firstDay']."','".$_POST['lastDay']."');
    insert into  IDC (name,id,phone,hpcid) VALUES('".$_POST['enName3']."','".$_POST['enID3']."','".$_POST['enPhone3']."',LAST_INSERT_ID());               
    insert into  IDC (name,id,phone,hpcid) VALUES('".$_POST['enName4']."','".$_POST['enID4']."','".$_POST['enPhone4']."',LAST_INSERT_ID());
    insert into  IDC (name,id,phone,hpcid) VALUES('".$_POST['enName5']."','".$_POST['enID5']."','".$_POST['enPhone5']."',LAST_INSERT_ID());
    commit;";
$stmt=$conn->query($query);
```

Here, the code of added while loop works failed:

```
$query="begin ;
        declare i int;
        set i = 5;
        insert into ".$_GET['table']." (name, begindate,enddate) VALUES('".$_POST['customerName']."','".$_POST['firstDay']."','".$_POST['lastDay']."');
       insert into  IDC (name,id,phone,hpcid) VALUES('".$_POST['enName3']."','".$_POST['enID3']."','".$_POST['enPhone3']."',LAST_INSERT_ID());                
       insert into  IDC (name,id,phone,hpcid) VALUES('".$_POST['enName4']."','".$_POST['enID4']."','".$_POST['enPhone4']."',LAST_INSERT_ID());
        while i<106
        do　
        insert into  IDC (name,id,phone,hpcid) VALUES('".$_POST["enName'+i+'"]."','".$_POST["enID'+i+'"]."','".$_POST["enPhone'+i+'"]."',LAST_INSERT_ID());
        set i = i +1;
        end while;
        commit;";
 $stmt=$conn->query($query);
```

I suppose "ename'+i+'" in while loop is wrong.I hava tried enNamei,enName$i,"enName"+i, but all of them are wrong style.

First of all, i want to realize that how to  inserting many row data into IDC table with while loop. For example 100 row data , like:

```
name     id    phone
john1     1    123
john2     2    234
john3     3    345
......
john100   100   3453
```

Who can help me ?